# Можно ли получать доход от рекламы admob в приложении, если его удалили с play market?

Tags: android, google-play

Наше приложение в плеймаркете уже больше года, но сегодня его удалили за якобы нарушение интеллектуальной собственности. Мы с этим вопросом разбираемся и возможно всё решится. Но хотелось бы узнать, в случае если приложение всё же будет недоступно в плеймаркете для пользователей и они будут устанавливать его например самостоятельно скачивая с нашего сайта, будет ли возможен доход от рекламы адмоб или реклама тоже будет заблокирована? Может кто-то сталкивался?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если аккаунт `AdMob` не заблокировали то для рекламы ничего не изменится - показыв будут, доходы будут, выплаты будут. Наличие APK файла в сторе на это никак не влияет.

Answer (score 3):

`Admob` на прямую не связан с `PlayMarket`.Вы можете вообще  `apk` загрузить его на китайские маркеты ему главное показы и их результативность.Так что не беспокойтесь

Answer (score 0):

а вот и нет, со временем вам на почту прийдет письмо о том, что для данного приложения заблокированы показы, т.к. приложение нарушает правила(и причина по которой его удалили из play market)